# How can I better write this procedural UV mapping for generated hexagons?

Tags: c#, textures, texture-mapping, vertex

I am trying to configure procedural UV mapping for dynamically generated meshes, but at the moment I'm not having much luck. I have a 1024x1024 texture, with tiles that are 256x in size amounting to 4 columns and 4 rows per texture. I am currently working with hexagons, and hitting a few stumbling blocks.

When the system is run... it generates this:

[image]

The texture atlas file in question is this, with a coordinate system based on 0 to 1 and 0,0 located in the lower left corner:

[image]

It should be a solid green hexagon. Everything is laid out within the loops and should match the vertexes, but it isn't working that way and I can't figure out what exactly is going on here. Is there a better way, or more efficient method that would correctly lay out the uv and scale to match the hexagons in the texture? The code I have so far is below. It primarily uses lists instead of arrays to accommodate additional structures.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class HexMesh: MonoBehaviour {

    Mesh hexMesh;
    MeshCollider meshCollider;
    public List<Vector3> vertices;
    public List<Vector2> uvs;
    List<int> triangles;

    int uvRows = 4;
    int uvCols = 4;
    float uvRadius;

    public Vector2 uvDefault;

    void Awake()
    {
        uvRadius = 1.0f / uvCols / 2.0f;
        uvDefault = new Vector2(uvRadius, uvRadius);
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = hexMesh = new Mesh();
        meshCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
        hexMesh.name = "Hex Mesh";
        vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        uvs = new List<Vector2>();
        triangles = new List<int>();
    }

    public void Triangulate(HexCell[] cells)
    {
        hexMesh.Clear();
        vertices.Clear();
        triangles.Clear();
        uvs.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
        {
            Triangulate(cells[i]);
        }

        hexMesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        hexMesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();

        hexMesh.uv = uvs.ToArray();
        meshCollider.sharedMesh = hexMesh;
        hexMesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    void Triangulate(HexCell cell)
    {
        Vector3 center = cell.transform.localPosition;
        addHex(center);
    }

    void addHex(Vector3 hexCenter)
    {
        int vertexIndex = vertices.Count;

        Vector2[] uvVerts = new Vector2[6];


        Vector3 v = Vector3.forward;
        for (var k = 0; k < HexMetrics.corners.Length; k++)
        {
            vertices.Add(v * HexMetrics.outerRadius);
            Vector3 uv = v * HexMetrics.outerRadius;
            uvVerts[k] = new Vector2(uv.x, uv.z);
            v = Quaternion.AngleAxis(60.0f, Vector3.up) * v;
        }

        triangles.Add(vertexIndex);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 5);

        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 5);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 4);

        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 4);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);

        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 3);
        triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 4);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            uvs.Add(uvVerts[j] + uvDefault);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks reasonable. Essentially, you are using the vertex position as uv coordinates. Why do you think the hexagon should be green?

Comment: The UV scale is 0-1 on a bottom left coordinate structure. The first hexagon tile in the 0,0 default position is green, but the "texture" being generated from it is black/white, of which no such direct tile exists. It seems like it's not returning correctly scaled X or Y values. I added some additional information to it. The "white line" appears to be from a very tiny dot I added at the 0.127 position it's drawing to test.

Answer (score 1):

With help from a second set of eyes, we figured out what the problem was - at least two parts. The first was in the code:

```
Vector3 uv = v * HexMetrics.outerRadius;
uvVerts[k] = new Vector2(uv.x, uv.z);
```

should be

```
uvVerts[k] = new Vector2(v.x, v.z) * uvRadius;
```

The second issue was that the tiling of the shader was set completely off, to 0,0 when it should have been 1,1.